# what is the difference between &c and *c declaration?

Tags: c++

I don't understand:
What is the difference between:

```
string Str ("Str");
char &C = Str [0];
```

and this:

```
string Str ("Str");
char *C = Str;
```

I don't understand this declaration actually:

```
char &C = Str [0];
```

?

Comment: think of references as constant pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differences between pointer (char* C) and reference(char &C):

1. Reference must be initialized at once, while pointer might not - you cannot just write `char &C`, you must write `char &C = ...;`, but `char *C;` is ok.
2. Once initialized, reference cannot change the address it refers to, while pointer can.

In other words, pointer can have a NULL-value and arithmetic operations can be performed with pointers.

Also `char &C` is in a manner equal to `char * const C`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have to "mix" between your answer and other ones, but yours is kinddof "clearer" to me. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
char &C = Str [0];
```

This makes `C` a reference to `Str[0]`. A reference is another way to access a variable. It's basically just a more elegant way to do the same thing pointers do. [There are some differences.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c).

Answer (score 0):

```
char &C = Str [0];
```

This references `c` to the first member of the `Str`. Accessing `c` will access `Str[0]`.

```
char *C = Str;
```

Here, `c` **points** to the first member of the `Str`. Accessing `c` will **not** access `Str[0]`. Accessing `*c` will.